# Apparent discrepancy in the calculated value of integrals using two different metods

Tags: probability, improper-integrals

The integral to be evaluated -

$I=\lambda\mu\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}min(x,y)e^{-\lambda x}e^{-\mu y}\, dx\,dy$

Now one approach can be using the fact that this integral can be treated as the expectation value of the exponential variable $min(x,y)$ whose rate constant is $\lambda+\mu.$(This is known from the property that the minimum of two independent exponential variables is itself an exponential variable .)

The other approach that I used was evaluating this integral analytically. Now the way this could be done is as follows-

Divide the first quadrant using the $x=y$ line such that $min(x,y)=y$ in the lower half and $min(x,y)=x$ in the upper half .

Now , the lower half integral -
$\lambda\mu\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{x}ye^{-\mu y}e^{-\lambda x}\,dy\, dx$
comes out to be $\frac{1}{\lambda+\mu}$

Similarly the upper half one would also be $\frac{1}{\lambda+\mu}$

and thus the total integral comes out to be  $\frac{2}{\lambda+\mu}$.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lambda\mu\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{x}ye^{-\mu y}e^{-\lambda x}\,dy\, dx=\lambda\mu\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda x}\int_{0}^{x}ye^{-\mu y}\,dy\, dx$$
$$=\lambda\mu\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda x}\frac{1-e^{-\mu x}(1+\mu x)}{\mu^2} dx=\frac{\mu}{(\lambda+\mu)^2}$$

The other integral is
$$\lambda\mu\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{x}^{\infty}xe^{-\mu y}e^{-\lambda x}\,dy\, dx=\frac{\lambda}{(\lambda+\mu)^2}$$